# Creating a public function inside a controller in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to create a public/private function inside my controller (say PostController) to tidy up certain code.

I wrote something like this:

```
class PostController extends BaseController
{      
    public function store()
    {
        $startdate = dateformatchange(Input::get('startdate'));
    }

    public function dateformatchange($date)
    {
        $dateString = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', $date);
        $dateNew = $dateString->format('Y/m/d');
        return $dateNew;
    }     
}
```

But I'm getting some error. `Call to undefined function dateformatchange()`

Am I doing it wrong? please advice where I went wrong. Sorry if it is a silly mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do it like this:

```
$startdate = $this->dateformatchange(Input::get('startdate'));
```

Comment: It shows another error:
`Call to a member function format() on a non-object`

Comment: Do you know why this happen?

Comment: Yes - because the date you are feeding to the DateTime object when you creating it is failing - probably because it is in the wrong format.